# Scraping text from html in python and then saving the text in a variable without \n operator

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, text, beautifulsoup

I have saved the text from an html file in a variable called 'data' using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
data = "ANALYSIS\n"
for header in soup.find_all('h2', text=re.compile('Analysis')):
    nextNode = header
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
        if nextNode is None:
            break
        if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
            if nextNode.name == "h2":
                break
            data = data + "\n\n" + nextNode.text
```

I need to do 2 things with my data variable:
1. Remove unwanted \n within a line, and
2. Keep the \n format between paragraphs but not showing \n when I call the data variable.

My aim is to save the data variable finally in an excel file.

currently my output is:

'ANALYSIS\n\n\nOVERVIEW\n\nFinancial improvement largely improved; TSR outperformed\npeers. All earnings and profitability-based measures showed year-over-year\nimprovements. \n\nANNUAL INCENTIVES\n\nIncentive metrics largely unchanged, although disclosure\nof target goals further enhanced. As in the prior year, the 2018 annual\nincentive program was comprised of five corporate categories: (i) Health,\nSafety, and Environmental, (ii) Operational, (iii) Financial, (iv) Strategic\nMilestones, and (v) TSR. The company disclosed certain metrics within each\ncategory including targets and payout matrices for relative metrics. Distinct\ntargets are disclosed for the three metrics underlying the strategic milestones\ncategory, which is an improvement over 2017 when goals within the metric were generally\nqualitative. There remains no disclosure of threshold or maximum goals, except\nfor relative metrics.

But my desired output is (to be a stored in an excel file):

ANALYSIS

OVERVIEW

Financial improvement largely improved; TSR outperformed peers. All earnings and profitability-based measures showed year-over-year improvements.

ANNUAL INCENTIVES

Incentive metrics largely unchanged, although disclosure of target goals further enhanced. As in the prior year, the 2018 annual incentive program was comprised of five corporate categories: (i) Health, Safety, and Environmental, (ii) Operational, (iii) Financial, (iv) Strategic Milestones, and (v) TSR. The company disclosed certain metrics within each category including targets and payout matrices for relative metrics. Distinct targets are disclosed for the three metrics underlying the strategic milestones category, which is an improvement over 2017 when goals within the metric were generally qualitative. There remains no disclosure of threshold or maximum goals, except for relative metrics.

Please advise on how I can save the data in this format? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need \n\n in what you are trying to do. What should be done rather is append the data to a list.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
data = ["ANALYSIS"]
for header in soup.find_all('h2', text=re.compile('Analysis')):
    nextNode = header
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
        if nextNode is None:
            break
        if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
            if nextNode.name == "h2":
                break
            data.append(nextNode.text)
```

This lets you do a number of file IO operations, including:

```py
with open("outfile.csv", "a") as output:
  for entry in data:
    outfile.write(data+"\n\n")
  outfile.close()
```

Here I am using a CSV as CSV is a markup-free Excel compatible filetype. Excel renders CSV files in the same format as a standard spread sheet.

To view the data, you would want to iterate though the array using:

```py
for entry in data:
  print(entry+"\n")
```

Which would give you:

ANALYSIS

OVERVIEW

Financial improvement largely improved; TSR outperformed peers. All earnings and profitability-based measures showed year-over-year improvements.